# Auto executar macros no Excel/VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Fiz várias tentativas de executar uma macro ao iniciar o Excel como indicado nas pesquisas que fiz, apesar dessas indicações serem muito simples, no meu caso não funcionaram.

Segui o seguinte roteiro:

1. Duplo clique sobre "Esta_pasta_de_trabalho" no Projeto do VBA, em "Microsoft Excel Objetos"
2. Preenchi o código como abaixo:

```vb
Public Sub Auto_Open()

    MsgBox ("Ok")

End Sub
```

3. Executei a macro gerada para teste e funcionou.
4. Salvei a planilha "habilitada para macros"
5. Fechei a planilha e a chamei, a planilha é aberta mas a macro não é executada.

Para testar, deixei um erro de sintaxe no código, salvei, fechei e chamei novamente, e nem o erro foi apresentado (ao executar a macro manualmente o erro é apresentado), ou seja, a macro de inicialização está sendo ignorada (verificação de sintaxe, justamente por não estar sendo executada).

Alterei algumas das configurações do Excel, como as de habilitação de macros, por exemplo, mas não surtiram efeito.

Antes estava testando a chamada de uma função pelo comando Call, chamando uma outra macro ou mandando abrir um formulário, e também não funcionaram.

O que está faltando ou o que está errado neste caso?

Comment: Só uma observação: **configurar o Excel para executar código automaticamente pode levar a graves brechas de segurança**. Isto não é recomendável em praticamente nenhuma ocasião, principalmente quando se fala num ambiente de trabalho, pois pode permitir a terceiros capturar e monitorar os dados do computador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, o código correto é:

```
 Sub Workbook_Open()

 MsgBox ("Ok")

 End Sub
```

Nos exemplos eram dados nomes diversos com o evento "Open", no meu caso só funcionou com "Workbook_Open". Pode-se usar Private Sub ou Public Sub, ou ainda Function (eu li que pode ser usada função, mas não testei).